# ReadExactlyAsync not cancellable?

Tags: c#, windows, async-await, serial-port

I have a program that communicates with a device over a virtual serial port.
I am working on making it async. However, it seems, that the underlying buffer methods do not honor cancellation, [as they should](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.io.stream.readexactlyasync?view=net-7.0).

```
var _serialPort = new SerialPort("COM1", 19200, Parity.None);

var cts = new CancellationTokenSource(TimeSpan.FromSeconds(5));
cts.Token.Register(() => Console.WriteLine("Cancelled"));

var buffer = new byte[10];

_serialPort.Open();

await Task.Run(async () =>
    {
        while (!cts.IsCancellationRequested)
        {
            Console.WriteLine("Waiting for data");
            await _serialPort.BaseStream.ReadExactlyAsync(buffer, cts.Token);
            Console.WriteLine("Got data");
        }
    });

Console.WriteLine("Done");
```

I got - with no data actually on the stream:

[image]

And that's it. What am I missing?

Comment: Do you get an exception or does the process hang?

Comment: @StephenCleary it just hangs. When I debug I don't get passed the readasync indifferent of the state of the token. I have tried wrapping into try-catch, but makes no difference. Yes it should throw an OperationCancelledException or something similar.

Comment: It's possible that serial port streams just don't support cancellation.

Comment: Reading the source code from https://github.com/dotnet/runtime, `SerialStream` [.Windows] does not implement `ReadAsync(Byte[], Int32, Int32, CancellationToken)`. The default behaviour of the base stream only checks for cancellation before calling `BeginRead` / `EndRead` which don't support cancellation, or read timeouts.